# Orderly streaming of parallel request in Flux

Tags: java, sorting, project-reactor

I'm looking for a way to use Flux to achieve the following:

1. Handle a stream of 1,000,000 (or more) requests.
2. The requests are numbered (from 1 to 1,000,000).
3. Requests should be launched in parallel using, say, 10 threads.
4. Launching order of the requests is determined by their serial numbers.
5. Result Flux should return the responses in the same order as the requests.
6. Result Flux should emit each response **AS SOON AS** all of its predecessors are available.

I know the answer to #4 is to use a single Executor for the Scheduler. However, I'm not sure how to achieve #6.

Here is an example scenario:

- Requests 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are launched.
- Response 2 arrives (request 11 launched, as there a thread becomes available).
- Response 5 arrives (request 12 launched).
- Response 4 arrives (request 13 launched).
- Response 1 arrives (request 14 launched).
- > Responses 1 and 2 are emitted and processing of them begins.
- Response 3 arrives (request 15 launched).
- > Responses 3,4,5 are emitted and processing of them begins.

So - how should I modify the below code in order to achieve #6?

```js
public class Example {

private final Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.fromExecutor(
 Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 ) );

public void start() {
 Flux<Request> requestFlux = getFluxOfOneMillionRequests(); // Never mind how this is achieved
 
 Flux<Response> responseFlux = flux.flatMap(request -> doInWorkerThread(request));
 
 flux.doOnNext(response -> processResponse(response)).subscribe()
}

private Mono<Response> doInWorkerThread(Request request) {

 return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

  // Do something
  return new Response( request.getSerial(), someResult );
 }).subscribeOn(scheduler);
}

private void processResponse(Response response) {
 // Do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a certain answer, although I resorted to using low-level thread synchronizing code.
The idea is to have 3 Flux steps:

- First step is handling requests in multiple threads, by subscribing a Mono on a Scheduler, which uses an Executor with multiple worker threads. When a worker thread finishes, it puts its response on a common list and returns some arbitrary object in order to activate the second step.
- The second step sends the "signal" from the worker thread to a single collecting thread. It does so by subscribing a Mono on **another** Scheduler, which uses a single thread Executor.
- The third step runs on a single thread. Every time it is called it extract the responses that came in order from the common list and returns them as Flux.

For the multi-threaded Scheduler I'm using a single Executor, in order to execute the tasks at the order they were inserted. This would decrease the average amount of responses the caching mechanism would have to hold.

This is demonstrated in the following code snippet:

```js
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class StreamSort {

    private final Scheduler produceScheduler = Schedulers.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3, new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("--> Producer-%d").build()));
    private final Scheduler consumeScheduler = Schedulers.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("<-- Consumer-%d").build()));
    private final ResponseReadySignal responseReadySignal = new ResponseReadySignal();
    private int nextExpected = 1;
    private List<Response> arrivals = Lists.newArrayList();

    private static class ResponseReadySignal {}
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        StreamSort m = new StreamSort();

        m.start();
    }

    private void start() throws InterruptedException {

        Flux<Request> requests = generateRequestFlux();

        requests
                .flatMap(request -> doInWorkerThread(request))
                .flatMap(signal -> jumpToCollectingThread(signal))
                .flatMap(signal -> departInOrder(signal))
                .doOnNext(response -> log("Got " + response ))
                .doOnComplete(() -> stopWaiting())
                .subscribe();

        waitUntilFinished();

        log("Disposing schedulers");
        produceScheduler.dispose();
        consumeScheduler.dispose();
        log("FINISH");
    }

    private synchronized void waitUntilFinished() throws InterruptedException {
        this.wait();
    }

    private synchronized void stopWaiting() {
        this.notifyAll();
    }

    private Flux<Request> generateRequestFlux() {
        List<Integer> serials = Lists.newArrayList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

        return Flux.fromIterable(serials).map(serial -> new Request(serial));
    }

    private Mono<ResponseReadySignal> doInWorkerThread(Request request) {

        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

            Response response = handleRequest(request);

            synchronized (this) {
                arrivals.add(response);
            }

            return responseReadySignal;
        }).subscribeOn(produceScheduler);
    }

    private Response handleRequest(Request request) throws InterruptedException {
        int milli = rand.nextInt(1000);

        log( request + " start, sleeping " + milli );

        Thread.currentThread().sleep( milli ); // Simulate some task that takes time

        log( request + " Finished" );

        return new Response(request.getSerial()); // Simulate response creation.

    }

    private Mono<ResponseReadySignal> jumpToCollectingThread(ResponseReadySignal signal) {

        log( "Delivering signal to collecting thread" );

        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> signal).subscribeOn(consumeScheduler);
    }

    private Flux<Response> departInOrder(ResponseReadySignal signal) {

        List<Response> readyToDepart = Lists.newLinkedList();

        synchronized (this) {
            Collections.sort(arrivals);
            while (arrivals.size() > 0 && arrivals.get(0).getSerial() == nextExpected) {
                readyToDepart.add(arrivals.remove(0));
                ++nextExpected;
            }
        }

        log("Departing " + readyToDepart.size() + " items: " + readyToDepart);
        return Flux.fromIterable(readyToDepart);
    }

    private static void log( String message ) {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println( t.getName() + ": " + message );

    }

    private static class WithSerial implements Comparable<WithSerial> {
        private final int serial;

        public WithSerial(int serial) {
            this.serial = serial;
        }

        public int getSerial() {
            return serial;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(WithSerial o) {
            return this.serial - o.serial;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "" + getSerial();
        }
    }

    private static class Request extends WithSerial {

        public Request(int serial) {
            super(serial);
        }
    }

    private static class Response extends WithSerial {
        public Response(int serial) {
            super(serial);
        }
    }
}
```